# maintain multi project modules with SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

How to maintain multi module dependencies with Apache spark 2.3 in one module and Apache spark 2.4 in another one. What would be the project layer and how build.sbt looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different dependencies for each module.

Let's assume you have module A and module B, it would look something like this:

```scala
lazy val moduleA = (project in file("moduleA"))
  .settings(
    name := "Module-A",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0")
  )

lazy val moduleB = (project in file("moduleB"))
  .settings(
    name := "Module-B",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0")
  )
```

The [official documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Multi-project+builds) is pretty good, there are several examples

Comment: Javier Monton - Thanks for the response. I have been doing this way and is facing issues with some conflicts.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572143/multi-module-sbt-projects-issues. This link explains the issue that I am facing. Any help is appreciated